# Jupyter with Julia results in unexpected type error: no method matching

Tags: julia, jupyter

I get an unexpected type error when running the following Julia code in Jupyter, where a seemingly straightforward import goes wrong:

```
include("./imp.jl")
include("./imp2.jl")
n = Main.Imp.Network([1,2])
Imp2.p2(n)
```

This results in the following error:

```
MethodError: no method matching p(::Main.Imp.Network)
Closest candidates are:
  p(::Main.Imp2.Imp.Network) at /Users/cg/Dropbox/code/Julia/learning/imp.jl:11
```

The code is the below. How does this happen?

Imp.jl:

```
module Imp

export Network, p

mutable struct Network
  a::Array{Any,1}
end

function p(network::Network)
  network
end

end
```

Imp2.jl:

```
module Imp2
include("./imp.jl")

function p2(network)
  Imp.p(network)
end

end
```

More error below:

```
Stacktrace:
 [1] p2(network::Main.Imp.Network)
   @ Main.Imp2 ~/Dropbox/code/Julia/learning/imp2.jl:5
 [2] top-level scope
   @ In[3]:4
 [3] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [4] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1116
```

Comment: you're include("./imp.jl") twice, DO NOT do this

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there a beginner-friendly way to describe why this works? I assume the included Type in `imp2` is a different type than the type defined in `imp`? To me this feels very unintuitive, would love to understand why. And of course would accept as the answer either way.

Comment: `include()` is literally copy-pasting the source code in that location, when you double include, you have two types with the same name under different modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do:

```
module Imp2
using Main.Imp
function p2(network)
  Imp.p(network)
end
end
```

OR (without sourcing `imp.jl` outside of module defintion)

```
module Imp2
include("./imp.jl")
using .Imp
function p2(network)
  Imp.p(network)
end
end
```

In the second case your Julia code could look like:

```
julia> using Main.Imp2

julia> n = Imp2.Imp.Network([1,2])
Main.Imp2.Imp.Network(Any[1, 2])

julia> Imp2.p2(n)
Main.Imp2.Imp.Network(Any[1, 2])
```

Addtionally if you add `export Imp` to the `Imp2` module, you could write `Imp.Network([1,2])` instead of `Imp2.Imp.Network([1,2])`.